# Wiener filter for vector-valued signal

Tags: power-spectral-density, kalman-filters, wiener-filter

I'm trying to understand the derivation of a Wiener filter for a vector-valued signal, found in the paper "[Kalman filtering in non-Gaussian model errors: a new perspective](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9770285)," IEEE Signal Processing Magazine, May 2022. This is the section headed "Smoothing Wiener filter" on p. 108.

The author starts out with a definition of the inputs and outputs (equation (4)),

$$
\hat{\mathbf{x}}_k = \mathbf{\Psi}_k * \mathbf{y}_k \approx \mathbf{x}_k
$$

where the state $\mathbf{x}_k$ and state estimate $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_k$ are vectors
and $\mathbf{\Psi}_k$ is a matrix, as I would expect. The input $\mathbf{y}_k$ is a
vector-valued measurement

$$
\mathbf{y}_k = \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_k + \mathbf{\eta}_k
$$

where $\mathbf{H}$ takes a state vector to a measurement vector, and $\mathbf{\eta}_k$
is a noise vector. All well and good so far.

But then the author presents an expression (equation (6)) for the Wiener
filter as follows,

$$
\mathbf{\Psi}(z) = S_{xy}(z) S_{yy}^{-1}(z) 
    = S_{xx}(z) \mathbf{H}^T \left( \mathbf{H} S_{xx}(z) \mathbf{H}^T 
    + S_{\eta\eta}(z) \right)^{-1}
$$

where $S_{xx}(z)$ and $S_{\eta\eta}(z)$ are power spectral densities
(PSDs).

Now I'm lost. I see that these are $z$-transforms, which is fine, but
the notation in the paper (not bold-faced) indicates that they are
scalar functions. In addition, they are functions of a single variable
$z$, again a scalar. Yet they are treated as matrices in the equations.

How can a vector-valued signal $\mathbf{x}_k$ in the time domain be
transformed to a function of a *single* variable $z$ in the $z$-domain?
I'm stuck on the definition of these PSDs. Are they matrices in reality,
in spite of the notation? Does that mean that each and every element of
$S_{xx}(z)$ is itself a scalar function of $z$?

**Edit:**

After a fresh look this morning, here's my best guess:

To avoid the proliferation of subscripts, write the two vectors
$\mathbf{x}_k$ and $\mathbf{y}_k$ as

$$
\mathbf{x}[k] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1[k] & x_2[k] & ... & x_m[k] 
\end{pmatrix}^T
$$

$$
\mathbf{y}[k] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1[k] & y_2[k] & ... & y_n[k] 
\end{pmatrix}^T
$$

Take the outer product of the two vectors to get an $m\times n$ matrix

$$
\mathbf{R}_{xy}[k] = 
\begin{pmatrix}
E[x_1[k]y_1[k]] & E[x_1[k]y_2[k]] & \dots & E[x_1[k]y_n[k]] \\
E[x_2[k]y_1[k]] & E[x_2[k]y_2[k]] & \dots & E[x_2[k]y_n[k]] \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
E[x_m[k]y_1[k]] & E[x_m[k]y_2[k]] & \dots & E[x_m[k]y_n[k]]
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $E[\cdot]$ is the expected value. Take the $z$-transform
to get the PSD

$$
S_{xy}(z) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \mathbf{R}_{xy}[k] z^{-k}
$$

Comment: I believe they **are** matrix functions, not scalars. You're right that the notation is inconsistent because $S_{xy}$, $S_{xx}$, and $S_{yy}$ are not bolded, but they can't be scalars if their subscripted generators ($x$ and $y$) are vectors.

Comment: @Peter K. Thanks for your comment. I've edited my question with a proposed definition. With luck, this is correct.